# Auto-populate accumulated time data in Excel into a calendar

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel tool that will help measure the amount of time our reps interact with clients, are on the phone, or doing claims research.  I have a functioning stopwatch that accumulates time each time you hit start.  However, I would like that accumulated time to be populated into a calendar on the current date each time the application is closed.  For example, rep has a total of 1:14:29 of client interaction on September 1st.  When she closes Excel, I would like that time data put into the cell representing September 1st.  Any ideas?  I've included the code for the stopwatch.

```
Dim StopTimer           As Boolean
Dim SchdTime            As Date
Dim Etime               As Date
Const OneSec            As Date = 1 / 86400#

Sub ResetBtn_Click()
    StopTimer = True
    Etime = 0
    [B3].Value = "00:00:00"
End Sub

Sub StartBtn_Click()
   StopTimer = False
   SchdTime = Now()
   [B3].Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
   Application.OnTime SchdTime + OneSec, "Sheet1.NextTick"
End Sub

Sub StopBtn_Click()
    StopTimer = True
    Beep
End Sub

Sub NextTick()
   If StopTimer Then
      'Don't reschedule update
   Else
      [B3].Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
      SchdTime = SchdTime + OneSec
      Application.OnTime SchdTime, "Sheet1.NextTick"
      Etime = Etime + OneSec
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you are storing the total elapsed time. I've created an example below, but please change it to suit your needs.

The key to solving your problem is in using the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event in the `ThisWorkbook` object. (Using the `Workbook_Open` event helps too, as you see below in my example.)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim todaysDate As Date
    Dim todaysRange As Range
    Dim dateRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    If Not StopTimer Then
        '--- turn off the timer if it's still running
        StopTimer = True
    End If

    todaysDate = Date

    '--- you'll have declare how and where you're storing the
    '    "hours on date" information. the example here is that
    '    you have a list of dates in column D. If you find the
    '    date then add the current timer value to it, if you
    '    don't find the date then create a new line for the
    '    date and hours
    Set dateRange = ws.Range("D:D")
    Set todaysRange = dateRange.Find(What:=todaysDate, _
                                     After:=dateRange.Cells(1, 1), _
                                     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                     SearchFormat:=False)
    If todaysRange Is Nothing Then
        '--- not found, create a new row at the end
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs( _
                           ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Value <> ""), 0).Row
        Set todaysRange = dateRange.Cells(lastRow, 1)
        todaysRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = todaysDate
        todaysRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
    End If
    todaysRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = todaysRange.Offset(0, 1).Value + _
                                     ws.Range("B3").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    '--- resets the timer value each time you open the
    '    workbook, so it appropriately starts from zero
    ws.Range("B3").Value = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peter.  The code works great, had to make a few minor tweaks but nothing crazy.  I have one question though.  Is there a way to have the date with accumulated time populate the cell directly below the previous day?  Right now it doesn't seem to do that.  Thanks again!